# Function returns invalid address

Tags: c, memory

UPD: Okay, I'm sorry, but apparently example I provided was not enough to reproduce my error, that is why I'll try to give more info on what I'm doing (I'm sorry again I thought it is same problem I have).
I'm developing "library" on c language and I want to initialize structure like this

```
// some_head.h
typedef struct phony phony;

phony* create_phony();
int action_on_phony(phony* target);
```

```
// some_head.c
#include "some_head.h"

typedef struct phony {
  GLFWwindow* window;
  int w, h;
} phony;
```

As I know, this way implementation of structure is hidden from user and he cannot access data in it, but still my library functions can work with it (some way of achieving encapsulation so to speak). So that's why I have some create function(constructor):

```
// some_head.c
phony* create_phony()
{
    phony* created = malloc(sizeof(phony));
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    created->w = 1920;
    created->h = 1080;
    created->window = glfwCreateWindow(1920/2, 1080/2, "Later", NULL, NULL);
    if (created->window)
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(created->window);
    return created;
}

int action_on_phony(phony* target)
{
      return !glfwWindowShouldClose(target->window); // <- raises BAD_ACCESS
}
```

This works fine inside `some_head.c`, but when I'm trying to use this `create_phony()` thing somewhere else (ex. `main()`) like this:

```
#include "some_head.h"

int main()
{
    phony* obj = create_phony(); // <- gets invalid address
    action_on_phony(obj); 
    return 0;
}
```

It returns invalid address to me and I cannot pass it to other functions in `some_head.c` since they get invalid address and raise `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when they try to work with this address.
I assume this comes due unknown implementation of `phony` struct (only some_head.c knows size of it after all), that main does not know what is this and makes this kind of thing. So my question is is there a way to properly return incomplete structure from `some_head.c` or find another way to encapsulate data inside `phony` structure?

Comment: The return type of that function is `void` – you're not allowed to return anything from it. (Your compiler will have warned you that `warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void`.)

Comment: Please create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Didn't you get a compiler warning?

Comment: Do **not** ignore compiler warnings...

Comment: @AKX oops, sorry I forgot to change return type in this example, I fixed this typo

Comment: @DLWHI Why would you post an example that's nowhere representative of your actual code?!

Comment: @AKX It is similar to my actual code, I just changed names and skipped all the unrelevant initialization lines and I just made a mistake with this void return type. In my case there is actually matching return types of phony* in create() function

Comment: Similar is not same. You should compile and run the code you show us to make sure it actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @DLWHI I compiled and ran your fixed code, and it doesn't crash for me.

Comment: @Gerhardh I already did this and I get same effect with invalid address being returned

Comment: @DLWHI Are you 100% sure you can reproduce this problem with the exact code you've now included in the question, because _I certainly can't_.

Comment: It's still not a [mre]. The code you show [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/MW9TMYsz8) (I only added missing header files and some added debug output).

Comment: @DLWHI With your updated example, you aren't checking whether `target->window` is non-NULL before passing it to `glfwWindowShouldClose`.

Comment: @AKX yeah, but it actually shouldn't be null when it gets to ```glfwWindowShouldClose``` as ```create_phony()``` actually creates object that is being returned as invalid address outside its scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function does not have a return value.

> This works fine inside some_head.c, but when I'm trying to use this
> create_phony() thing somewhere else

2. It is because the typedef of the struct should be in the **`.h`** file as well. Otherwise you have only forward declaration but compiler does not have any clue what is the size of this structure.

You need to have its declaration (prototype) in the **`.h`** file which has to be included in the code which calls this function.

```
phony *create_phony(void);
```

And then in a **`.c`** file its definition:

```
phony *create_phony(void)
{
    phony* obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
    if(obj)
    {  
        // init
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Notes:

1. use objects not types in `sizeof`s.
2. always check the result of `malloc` family functions.

Comment: Why using objects in ```sizeof```s is more preferable than types?

Comment: Imagine what will happen if change the type but forget to change it in the `sizeof`

Comment: yeah, that would be a disaster but the problem is changing to ```malloc(sizeof(*obj))``` actually solved the issue and I do not know why.    
UPD: I will write an answer as I understand why it solved the problem

Comment: @DLWHI your typedef has to be in the .h file not in the .c file. See amended answer